# grub rescue error

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

i have windows 8. i removed uefi settings(if i on uefi i cannot install ubuntu) and installed ubuntu(now if i want to use windows 8 i should on uefi).now by turning on uefi,went to window8,removed ubuntu and i tried to install ubuntu once again by turning down uefi,then i got the error error:no such partition grub rescue.i turned on uefi and i am able to log in to windows with no errors but if i turn off uefi and try to install i am getting that error.

i dont have win8 cd

**can i get rid of this error by installing some other linux distro say fedora?**

Answer (score 0):

Windows is installed in UEFI mode, so you need to convert your Ubuntu from Legacy mode to UEFI mode. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_EFI_mode

Comment: i removed ubuntu from win8 and now I'm Stuck at the 'grub rescue>' Prompt .
and if i try to boot ubuntu once again with livecd(i can go back to win8 by switching to uefi mode) it is not able to boot and i dont have win8 cd to repair it .
i tried to reboot using ubuntu livecd but it is not recognising the cd.
please help me .
if the same question is already asked pls redirect me.